# AS3 print with button

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-edge

When I try to print my stage it results wrongly rotated. I tried to fix it, I googled 150 different solutions pages at least, without any luck. I am not the programmer I try to be. Anyway it should work but it doesn't. Can you help me please?

I tried to do that: when I click "print" button, I would like to save my page(sprit) as a `pdf` file but per default settings the page must be landscape oriented. 
Furthermore, there is a drawing (I use someone's code which shared in web) in stage but I don't want save the whole scene (for example buttons). I want to save just the drawing. Thanks for your help.

*İ used this (didn't work at all. even drawing didn't work.)*

```
btnPrint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);
function onPrintClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var bd :BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height, false);
    bd.draw(stage); 
    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap (bd); 
    var s:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
    s.addChild(b); 
    var myPrintjob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();   
    myPrintjob.start();
    var printArea = new Rectangle( 23, 65, 650, 500 ); 
    myPrintJob.addPage( s, printArea );
    myPrintJob.send();
}
```

*I tried also this approach (draw and print worked but orientation was wrong):*

```
btnPrint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);
function onPrintClick(event:Event)void{
    var myPrintjob:PrintJob = newPrintJob;
    myPrintjob.start();
    myPrintjob.addPage(this)
    myPrintjob.send;
}
```

I also tried some code I don't remember. It was like oriented.landscape and rotation 90, or something like that. It didn't work too. Probably I didn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're publishing for AIR** you can change page orientation using [PrintJob.orientation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#orientation).
You need to set that before calling `start()`. In your code example it would look something like this:

```
btnPrint.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);
function onPrintClick(event:Event)void{
    var myPrintjob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
    myPrintJob.orientation = PrintJobOrientation.LANDSCAPE; 
    myPrintjob.start();
    myPrintjob.addPage(this)
    myPrintjob.send();
}
```

Unfortunately this property is not settable if building for Flash Player.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesnt work. Error is this : "1059 property is read-only.". İt doesnt let us to change. Can you help me about what i can do?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it looks like you can only set that property if you're publishing for AIR. It's read-only for Flash Player. I'll add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used these codes and they did the job. Thanks for your efforts.

```
function onPrintClick(event:Event):void{
var bd :BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height, false);
bd.draw(stage); 
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap (bd); 
var s:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
s.addChild(b); 
var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();   
pj.start();
pj.orientation = PrintJobOrientation.LANDSCAPE;
var printArea = new Rectangle( Cw, Ch, 650, 500 );
pj.addPage(this);    
pj.send();
}
```